# The Baumslag-Solitar Group $G=\langle a, b\, \mid\, b^{-1}ab=a^2\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle a, b\, \mid\, b^{-1}ab=a^2\rangle$.

I want to prove that the normal closure of $a$ is isomorphic with the additive group of all rational numbers whose denominators are powers of $2$. I set out $k/2^h \mapsto b^{-h}a^kb^h$. To prove that this is an isomorphism I need to show that $o(a)=\infty$, how can I do that?

(Of course, I know that $o(b)=\infty$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a homomorphism $G \to {\rm GL}_2({\mathbb Q})$ with

$b \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$,
$a \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&1\end{array}\right)$.

Just check that the images of $a$ and $b$ satisfy the group relation to verify that this defines a homomorphism. The image of $a$ has infinite order, and hence so does $a$. This map is actually injective, and the image of the normal closure of $a$ consists of all matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\m/2^k&1\end{array}\right)$ with $m \in {\mathbb Z}$, $k \ge 0$.